# AVAudioPlayer closed while starting the app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, avaudioplayer

When I start my app on iphone at that time my `AVAudioPlayer` gets closed. and I want that when I start my app in background `AVAudioplayer` should be **on** and when I close my app `AVAudioPlayer` started automatically. Why does this happen. can anyone tell me?

Answer (score 0):

use following to activate sharedInstance of AudioPlayer while app is in background

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
```

Also for more code refer [Play one instance of AVAudioPlayer in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609780/play-one-instance-of-avaudioplayer-in-the-background)