# Play one instance of AVAudioPlayer in the background

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, avaudioplayer

I have several instances of AVAudioPlayer in my app (in separate classes). I have added multi-tasking capabilities to one instance but all audio now plays in the background. I added the 'App plays audio' key to my plist and:

```
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
```

to my class. How can I target this code to only 1 instance of AVAudioPlayer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way around this I could find was the pause the specific AVAudioPlayer instance in:

```
applicationWillResignActive
```

I moved the creation of the instance to the appdelegate and then accessed it via:

```
appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
```

in my class. There is probably a better way to do this but this was the quickest and simplest I could find.